Difficulties with an existence and uniqueness proof
Have been trying to prove this for 2 hours straight.
I'm asked to prove that there is a unique $A \in P(U)$ such that for every $B \in
P (U)$, $A \cap B = A$. I understand that $A=\emptyset$ satisfies the existence part, but can't prove the uniqueness part.
Here are my two attempts:

Suppose $C \subseteq U$ and $C \cap B = C$. Suppose $C\neq \emptyset$...? My intuition tells me that it's the right path but i don't know how to proceed. This assumption doesn't seem to lead to any contradictions.

Suppose $\forall C \in P(U) : C \cap B =C$ and suppose $\forall G \in P(U) : G \cap B =G$...? I'm almost sure that it's not the way to prove uniqueness, don't see how I can show that C=G from that.


Could you please give me a hint?

For 1) You need to assume that C ∩ B = C for any B in P(U). Consider when B = ∅

Suppose $A\in\mathcal P(U)$ and $\forall B\in\mathcal P(U)(A\cap B=A)$. That means $A\cap\emptyset=A$ since $\emptyset\in\mathcal P(U)$. Since $A\cap\emptyset=\emptyset$, we have $A=\emptyset$.

I've proven three theorems uning the technique you give in your answer but it still puzzles me. It seems strange and counterintuitive to me that we assume arbitrariness of A yet let $A=A_0$ to prove something about some other object. Could you clarify this, please?

I assumed $B=\emptyset$ to prove $A=\emptyset$. Example: Let $a$ be a real number such that $\forall b\in\mathbb R(a+b=b)$. Then we can set $b=0$ to get $a=0$.

A standard method to prove uniqueness is to assume you have two things satisfying the property, and then show that this means they must be equal.
Assume there exist $A$ and $A'$ in $P(U)$ that have the desired property:

For all $B\in P(U)$, $A\cap B=A$;
For all $C\in P(U)$, $A'\cap C=A'$.

By 1, taking $B=A'$, we conclude that $A\cap A'=A$. By 2, taking $C=A$l we conclude that $A'\cap A=A'$. Therefore,
$$A =A\cap A' =A'\cap A = A',$$
so $A=A'$.
This proves that there is at most one set $A$ with the desired property. If you've proven that there is at least one such set, you are done.
